# Primefaces datatable with treetable

Tags: primefaces

I want to develop  a table with pagination in primefaces. I found that the datatable in 
primefaces supports pagination. But for each row of that table I have a tree structure which opens on clicking the expander arrow. 
Can you please let me know how to achieve this in primefaces ?

-- row 1
-- row 2
-- row 3 (say user expanded this)
     - row 31
     - row 32
     - row 33
-- row 4

```
             < pagination links >
```

Thanks,
Avinash.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use primefaces treeTable

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeTable.jsf

this link has examples on how to use